# MS Excel 2010 Count unique values with multiple criteria and EDATE

Tags: arrays, date, count, excel-2010, unique

I am trying to get a count of all Unique values listed in Col A, by state and within a date range, for example all records up to the end of April 2018.

I am able to get the count of Unique values by state (result is 2) with the below formula:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(1*(FREQUENCY(IF($C$2:$C$14=F10,MATCH($A$2:$A$14,$A$2:$A$14,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$14)-ROW($A$2))>0))}
```

but I am unable to get the IF function to work with EDATE. I tried the following but I'm getting 0 as the result. The result should be 1.

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(1*(FREQUENCY(IF(D2:D14="<"&EDATE(G1,1),IF($C$2:$C$14=F10,MATCH($A$2:$A$14,$A$2:$A$14,0))),ROW($A$2:$A$14)-ROW($A$2))>0))}
```

I am unable to use Pivot as I need to include date range filter. Could someone please look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I am using CSE with my formulas. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out. EDATE wasn't working so I entered the Month date in cell:G1 then referenced it in the IF formula using "<=" eg: IF(D2:D14<=G1).

Whole array formula is:

```
`{=SUMPRODUCT(1*(FREQUENCY(IF(D2:D14<=G1,IF($C$2:$C$14=F10,MATCH($A$2:$A$14,$A$2:$A$14,0))),ROW($A$2:$A$14)-ROW($A$2))>0))}
```

I now receive the correct count of 1, though I have to ensure I have entered the last day of the Month in G1. State is referenced in F10 and count of unique values is in Column A.

My full data set is sourced from multiple documents over 5000 rows each and growing daily so my workbook is quite slow to calculate over 1000 array formulas... but it works!

If anyone knows of a faster (possibly non-array) formula, I would appreciate the advice! Thanks!